# running apt-get update on a non-networked computer (using data from another similar computer)

Tags: apt

I have two computers:

One has network access (N), the other doesn't (NN).

So I install Ubuntu (11.10) fresh on both N and NN.

On N (the networked machine) - I run 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get upgrade'.

Now, on NN (the non-networked machine), I want to do the same.  But NN wants a network connection to do the update and the upgrade.

I know what to do for the 'apt-get upgrade' part: I just copy the .deb files on N in the directory /var/cache/apt/archives/* to /var/cache/apt/archives/. on NN.  Then apt upgrades from the local cache instead of wanting a network.

HOWEVER:  How do I do the equivalent for the 'apt-get update' part?  If I just copy the .bin files in /var/cache/apt on N to NN, then the system thinks I have already upgraded.

Thanks

Cecil